# Network Error correction

Tags: networking, encoding, network-programming, decode, encode

I need to make simulator to simulate sending say 4-bit data word after converting it into a code-word then receiving it with the possibility of noise and error happening throughout the process .
The simulator needs to correct at least 3 errors.

the problem is I've been reading for hours about error detection and correction and it only talks about correcting 1 bit of error at most !

Linear hamming distance tables wouldn't work well (performance-wise) on more than 1 bit error correction .

Is there anyway to do this ? I just need a guideline 
Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you are looking for Forward Error Correction; where you pre-calculate some "parity" data, append it to your original data, and then on reception, you regenerate the original data (detecting/correcting errors) and discard the parity.

If you are using C/C++, Javascript or Python, you can use https://github.com/pjkundert/ezpwd-reed-solomon.  This library (available for use under GPLv3, LGPL and Commercial licenses) provides a simple, very fast implementation of Reed-Solomon FEC encoding and decoding.

It supports "symbol" (data element) sizes from 2 to 16 bits.  The maximum "codeword" (data + parity) size depends on the number of bits in the word.  For example, for 4-bit symbols, the maximum codeword size is 15 symbols.  So, each block of data could be from 1 to 14 symbols, with the remaining parity symbols (totalling 15) generated by the Reed-Solomon encoder to produce the R-S "codeword".  Later, when the symbols are received, the Reed-Solomon decoder validates and/or corrects the "codeword", and discards the parity symbols.

In C++, you would need to unpack your binary data into 4-bit symbols (probably just an array or std::vector of unsigned char, where each char holds a value from 0 to 15).

Then, decide how much error you want to correct for.  Each erroneous symbol requires 2 Reed-Solomon parity symbols, so to correct for 3 errors, you need 6 parity symbols.  You would use your expected error rate to determine the maximum number of symbols you can group together before you would expect to see 3 erroneous symbols.

Lets say your maximum expected error rate is 15%.  So, you'd be able to collect 20 symbols before you would expect 3 bad symbols.  Since the 6 parity symbols can also be erroneous, they are included in the 20.   So, ideally, you would like to take 14 data symbols, then add 6 parity symbols for a total of 20 symbols in a codeword.

Problem is, your maximum R-S codeword size is 15, for 4-bit symbols.  R-S codecs always have a maximum codeword size, for N-bit symbols, of 2^N-1.  Hence for 4-bit symbols, 2^4-1 is 15 -- hence, an RS(15,...) codec is what you'll be using.  The second number is the payload size -- the number of non-parity symbols.  Therefore, for 6 parity -- RS(15,9).  So, you'll be getting a bit more error resolving power than you need, using an RS(15,9) codec, being able to resolve 3 errors in every 15 symbols.

So, cut up your data into 9-symbol chunks.  Create an ezpwd::rs::RS<15,9> instance, and use its encode method to add the 6 parity symbols.  Send that out in your simulation.

After your simulator adds some errors, receive 15-symbol chunks, and run each chunk through the decode method of your RS<15,9> codec.  It will return the number of erroneous symbols corrected -- or throw an exception, if the error load exceeds the capacity of the Reed-Solomon encoding.

Have fun!